# How to get kite historical api through postman

Tags: python, java

I am using kite api for automate transaction. I want to get historical data from kite api through postman,but i didn't got.

Comment: please describe the issue in detail

Comment: where describe "Authorization: token api_key:access_token" and "X-Kite-Version: 3" in postman.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.